# Añadir comprobación de campo oculto en contact form7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Para evitar el recaptcha de google ya que relantiza la web muchisimo ya que añade mas de 10 consultas y eso hace que la web sea muchisimo mas lenta quería saber como puedo añadir una funciona para que valide un campo de texto oculto en mi formulario, he de tener en cuenta que uso wordpress y un plugin para crear formularios que es el contact form7, no se como añadir la comprovación de este campo y que si esta vacio se envie el mail sino esta vacio que no se envie ya que sera spam

Comment: Quizás esto te sirva: [contact-form-7-honeypot](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-honeypot/) y si no creas tu propio [honeypot](https://www.google.es/search?espv=2&q=honeypot+javascript+php&oq=honeypot+javascript+php&gs_l=serp.3...1714.3337.0.3609.11.9.0.0.0.0.368.1032.0j2j0j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..10.0.0.LR_qHpFypqE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solución, añado un flitro para la comprobación.

```
function comprobacionspam ($result,$tag){
$type = $tag['type'];
$name = $tag['name'];
if($name == 'comprobacion'){
$comprobacion = isset( $_POST['comprobacion'] ) ? trim( $_POST['comprobacion'] ) : '';
if($comprobacion != "" ){ 
$result->invalidate( $tag, "It's not humman" );
}
}
return $result;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text','comprobacionspam', 10, 2);
```